# The h1 header title is not being responsive to my website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

All was going well when designing a responsive website till I decided to start styling my `header` to my choice of design with `font-family`, `font-size` and its `letter-spacing` to my liking, then everything became a bit weird once I resized it down to mobile when it is less than `600px`.

Why is my header now sticking out of my `<body></body>` in a weird way even though my `<div class = "header></div>` is still inside the `<body></body>` tag. ***See screenshot*** Any help would be much appreciated.

**Here is my HTML and CSS**

[image: header weird]

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The header section */

.header {
 background-color: #ccccff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 80px;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 68px;
 font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
}

/* The main content section */

.content {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

.content h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.content p {
 margin: 30px;
}

/* Three equal columns */

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* This is the footer section */
footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 background: lightgreen;
}

/* Responsive design starts here */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .column {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Title Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- This is a header -->
 <div class="header">
  
  <h1>Website Title</h1>
  <p>Dolor sed veniam minim eiusmod sint labore elit lilamco dolor in in dolor clipa occaecat do.</p>

 </div>

 <!-- This is the main content -->
 <div class="content">

  <!-- About section -->

  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum clipa nlila tempor amet dolor clipa magna commodo minim. Sed ut lilamco veniam est esse tempor in anim excepteur lilamco excepteur deserunt ad. Lorem ipsum tempor eiusmod nisi consectetur magna cupidatat in ad velit clipa aliqua id sunt clipa nlila aliqua laboris.
  </p>

  <!-- 3 column responsive layout -->

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>


    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>


    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>

  </div>



 </div>

 <!-- This is the footer -->
 <div class="footer">
  <footer>
   Person Name &copy; 2019
  </footer>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `font-size: 68px;` -- there is nothing responsive here, you probably want some media queries to reduce that font size on smaller screens.

Comment: you can use `em` for font-size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My class <h1> header is sticking out of <body> page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367567/my-class-h1-header-is-sticking-out-of-body-page)

Comment: @Nitheesh Revti Shah was able to help me out. Turns out it wasn't the "break-word". It was the "padding" in my "header" that I have to reduce when at a certain pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you.You just need to put css in media query for **.header and .header h1** of those classes to reduce padding as well as font-size. IF any changes please let know.

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The header section */

.header {
 background-color: #ccccff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 80px;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 68px;
 font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
}

/* The main content section */

.content {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #e6e6e6;
}

.content h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.content p {
 margin: 30px;
}

/* Three equal columns */

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* This is the footer section */
footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 background: lightgreen;
}

/* Responsive design starts here */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .column {
  width: 100%;
 }
  .header{
  padding: 10px;
  }
  .header h1{
  font-size:40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Title Page</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- This is a header -->
 <div class="header">
  
  <h1>Website Title</h1>
  <p>Dolor sed veniam minim eiusmod sint labore elit lilamco dolor in in dolor clipa occaecat do.</p>

 </div>

 <!-- This is the main content -->
 <div class="content">

  <!-- About section -->

  <h2>About</h2>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum clipa nlila tempor amet dolor clipa magna commodo minim. Sed ut lilamco veniam est esse tempor in anim excepteur lilamco excepteur deserunt ad. Lorem ipsum tempor eiusmod nisi consectetur magna cupidatat in ad velit clipa aliqua id sunt clipa nlila aliqua laboris.
  </p>

  <!-- 3 column responsive layout -->

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>


    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>


    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>
       Magna velit dolor esse magna ut sed cillum magna lilamco nisi ut. Qui labore in sed ea excepteur clipa laboris pariatur irure fugiat fugiat dolor qui. Velit aliquip fugiat eu ea dolor velit proident veniam consectetur ut dolor clipa sunt incididunt veniam duis nisi tempor.
      </p>
      <ul>
       <li>Skill 1</li>
       <li>Skill 2</li>
       <li>Skill 3</li>
       <li>Skill 4</li>
       <li>Skill 5</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>

  </div>



 </div>

 <!-- This is the footer -->
 <div class="footer">
  <footer>
   Person Name &copy; 2019
  </footer>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! That solved my problem! Seems like padding does like to cause issues a lot when people try to make a responsive websites.

Answer (score 2):

The type is too large to render in the provided space. You have a couple options: reduce the font-size, or tell the browser to split the text before a word-boundary using `word-break: break-word`.